# Can't use % in string as a url to fetch json Android

Tags: java, android, json, url

I'm not able to use % in a string with a url for fetching json data from that url, its showing IOException in Android Studio

Comment: In Android Studio? Dont think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent sign has a special meaning in a URL, it represents an encoded character.  So to put the percent sign in the URL, you have to URL-encode the percent sign itself.  When you do, you get %25.  If you replace % with %25, you should see what you expect.

If you are having this problem you should read the [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) to understand what URL encoding/decoding is and why you need it. Also have a look at the `java.net.URLEncoder` class.

Comment: i get the json using a normal %, but the problem is i cant use it in a String variable in Android Studio, Java

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/ If you post the code snippet with the problem, the resulting stack trace or a detailed description of the problem, you can get a more detailed solution from the community.